# Running TextView failure/Bug (Singleline marquee)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, marquee

Im trying to let my textview run from left to right in an infinite way.But somehow it looks really weird I even cant explain it in words so I decided to record and upload it.

Here is the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj3FF7fEutk&feature=youtu.be

So thats how I wrote my Textview :

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView_title_full"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And this TextView is in a RelativeLayout declared like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/BELOW_FULL"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/color_below_player_full"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager_albumart_full"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

where the RelativeLayout is also in a Relativelayout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="#0E0E0E">
```

I of course used the `txt_song_title.setSelected(true);` method.

How it looks like what I want to achieve :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4uAA4pik68

**Thank you all very much !**

**EDIT:**

All parts where I do sth with my TextView :

```
public void init_textviews()
{
        ...
        txt_song_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_title_full);
        txt_song_title.setSelected(true);
}
```

//`init_textviews()` is called in my onCreate method

```
txt_song_title.setText("Some Long text"); // called in onCreate after init_textviews()
```

And lastly:

```
public static void update_GUI_full (Context context) //Called when it is a button is clicked
{
    ...
    txt_song_title.setText("longTexthere");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are doing `txt_song_title.setText()`?

Comment: I allready tried it when I set a long text in xml with "android:text="Long Text here"" . So it actually cant be the method where Im using it

Comment: I just copied the xml file 1to1 to a new project and It works fine :/  And if it helps you Im doing the setText method in my onCreate section

Comment: I was about to ask you to create a new Activity with just your marquee ;) The marquee resets it's movement each time a setText is called. Can you post all the relevant code affecting your marquee? For example initialization, AsyncTasks, Handlers, etc...

Comment: I tried to debug and watch out all setText methods how often they are called and it looks like only once when the activity is created :/ Debug would show how often it is called wouldnt it ?

Comment: If you set a break point, the debugger will stop every time the method is called. And what about your RelativeLayouts? Are you updating them somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107375/discussion-between-ahmet-kazaman-and-antonio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working side by side with @Ahmet Kazaman we've found that there seemed to be a problem when combining a marquee `TextView` with another `TextView` periodically updated using a `Handler`.

After some tests we've found that this strange behaviour only happens when the `TextView`s are iside a `RelativeLayout` and everything woeks as expected when the enclosing layout is a `LinearLayout`. Thus, the solution (more a workaround) is to change the enclosing layout to be a `Linearlayout`.